# Strange CFSEARCH error in ColdFusion 11/SOLR

Tags: java, pdf, search, solr, coldfusion

I am getting a strange exception thrown every time I call `CFSEARCH` on my collection

Code:

```
<cfsearch
    name="qCollectionSearch_docs"
    collection="mydocuments"
    criteria="#LCase(Trim(LOCAL.Criteria))#"
    contextPassages="1"
    contextHighlightBegin=""
    contextHighlightEnd="" />
```

Exception:

```
Detail: Error executing query : Unexpected EOF; was expecting a close tag for element 
Message: There was a problem while attempting to perform a search.
StackTrace: coldfusion.tagext.search.SearchTag$SearchProblemException: There was a problem while attempting to perform a search.
    at coldfusion.tagext.search.SolrUtils.formatSearchResult(SolrUtils.java:2022)
    at coldfusion.tagext.search.SolrUtils.getSearchResult(SolrUtils.java:2516)
    at coldfusion.tagext.search.SearchTag.doSolrSearch(SearchTag.java:394)
    at coldfusion.tagext.search.SearchTag.doSearch(SearchTag.java:243)
    at coldfusion.tagext.search.SearchTag.doStartTag(SearchTag.java:185)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._emptyTcfTag(CfJspPage.java:2991)
```

This code has worked without incident in the past, but suddenly started throwing this exception on every request.

The collection is built with the following code:

```
<cfindex
    query="LOCAL.qDocuments"
    collection="mydocuments"
    action="refresh"
    type="file"
    key="DocumentFile"
    custom1="SKU"
    custom2="Status" />
```

...where LOCAL.qDocuments is a SQL query that retrieves the `SKU` and `Status` values from a database and `DocumentFile` is a path to a PDF document (i.e. `C:\PDFs\document1.pdf`).

The server is a virtual server running:

- OS: Windows Server 2012 with all of the latest updates
- IIS: 8.5
- ColdFusion: 11 with all of the latest updates
- Java: JRE 8 v111

I have tried restarting the `ColdFusion 11 Application Server` service and the `ColdFusion 11 Add-on Services` service, but this did not help.

Comment: My guess would be a corrupt index. Try optimizing with cfcollection - or purge and recreate it.

Comment: @MarkAKruger Thank you, I will give that a shot....

Comment: @MarkAKruger Optimizing the Collection did not work. I have purged the collection in CF Admin and I running the index script again to see if that helps.

Comment: @MarkAKruger Purging and re-indexing (and restarting the add-on services again) had no effect. Same error.

Answer (score -1):

Pass the value of the key, rather than the word 'documentFile':

```
<cfindex
key="#documentFile#"
/>
```

Comment: The issue is not with the CFINDEX. The CFINDEX has worked and continues to work correctly. The key value is correct. It expects the name of a Query column in this instance.

Comment: @Eric Belair, your last comment is incorrect. You now say that _documentFile_ is a column-name. Whereas you previously said, _"DocumentFile is a path to a PDF document (i.e. C:\PDFs\document1.pdf)."_

Comment: Sorry.... `documentFile` is a query column that represents a dynamically-generated file path:SELECT 
        '#APPLICATION.ProcessedPDFDir#'
            CONCAT '\'
            CONCAT TRIM(PSDOCID)
            CONCAT '.PDF'   AS  DocumentFile